# Converting 2D ArrayList to 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've looked at several answers already, and I am getting errors with the answers that I've found. I'm trying to convert an ArrayList of Doubles[] to a normal double 2D array. My code:

```
    public ArrayList<Double[]>  ec;
    public double[][]           ei;
    ...
    encogCorpus = new ArrayList<Double[]>();
    ...
    ec.add(inputs);
    ...
    ei = new double[ec.size()][];

    for (int i = 0; i < ec.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<Double> row = ec.get(i);
        ei[i] = row.toArray(new double[row.size()]);
    }
```

I'm getting errors that say

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Double[] to ArrayList

And

> The method toArray(T[]) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (double[])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problems

> 1. First of all, `ec` here is of type `ArrayList<Double[]>`, which means `ec.get(i)` should return `Double[]` and not `ArrayList<Double>`.
> 2. Second, `double` and `Double` are completely different types. You can't simply use `row.toArray(new double[row.size()])` on your code.

---

### Solutions

#### 1.

If you want a true 2D `ArrayList` of `Doubles` then the type of `ec` should be `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>`. But because we can't use `toArray()`, we manually loop instead.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> ec;  // line changed here
public double[][]                   ei;
...
encogCorpus = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>(); // and here also
...
ec.add(inputs); // `inputs` here should be of type `ArrayList<Double>`
...
ei = new double[ec.size()][];

for (int i = 0; i < ec.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<Double> row = ec.get(i);

    // Perform equivalent `toArray` operation
    double[] copy = new double[row.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < row.size(); j++) {
        // Manually loop and set individually
        copy[j] = row.get(j);
    }

    ei[i] = copy;
}
```

#### 2.

But if you insist of using `ArrayList<Double[]>`, we only need to change the main part:

```
public ArrayList<Double[]>  ec;
public double[][]           ei;
...
encogCorpus = new ArrayList<Double[]>();
...
ec.add(inputs);
...
ei = new double[ec.size()][];

for (int i = 0; i < ec.size(); i++) {
    // Changes are only below here

    Double[] row = ec.get(i);
    double[] copy = new double[row.length];

    // Still, manually loop...
    for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
        copy[j] = row[j];
    }

    ei[i] = copy;
}
```

#### 3.

Finally, if you could change `Double[]` to `double[]`, solution **2** would become,

```
public ArrayList<double[]>  ec; // Changed type
public double[][]           ei;
...
...
for (int i = 0; i < ec.size(); i++) {
    // Simpler changes here
    ei[i] = ec.get(i).clone();
}
...
```

Comment: I changed ec to public ArrayList<double[]> and the ec.add(inputs) seems to work, but the '// Changes are only below here' doesn't work then.

Comment: @jonbon, my mistakes, there was a weird typo!

Comment: @jonbon, I have edited my answer! But still, I can't believe I didn't saw that, and no one also saw that.

Comment: I am able to change to double[] instead of Double[]. Will I only need to use 1 for loop and use clone() then?

Comment: @jonbon I recommend `clone`. Its faster, both by typing and by runtime :)

Comment: Should it look like this then: for (int i = 0; i < ec.size(); i++) {
  ei[i] = ec.get(i).clone();
  }

Comment: I've been doing a number of tests, and ec has the correct data until I go and use 3., and then the data is incorrect. Something about the copying over is not working.

Comment: @jonbon Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83885/discussion-between-jason-sparc-and-jonbon).

Answer (score 3):

Basically all you need to do is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ec.size(); i++) {
    Double[] boxedRow = ec.get(i);
    double[] unboxedRow = new double[boxedRow.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < boxedRow.length; j++)
        unboxedRow[j] = boxedRow[j];
    ei[i] = unboxedRow;
}
```

You're having trouble because of boxing / unboxing. Manually unboxing the `Doubles` to `doubles` allows us to convert the array to the right type.

An alternate solution would be this:

```
public ArrayList<Double[]>  ec;
public Double[][]           ei; // no need to unbox

// ...

for (int i = 0; i < ec.size(); i++) {
    ei[i] = ec.get(i);
}
```

I'll add that your current solution is not a 2D `ArrayList`; it is an `ArrayList` of `Double` arrays. It looks like what you *might* be trying to do is something like this:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>  ec;
public double[][]                    ei;

// ...

for (int i = 0; i < ec.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<Double> row = ec.get(i);
    Double[] rowArray = row.toArray(new Double[row.size()]);
    double[] unboxedRow = new double[rowArray.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < rowArray.length; j++)
        unboxedRow[j] = rowArray[j];
    ei[i] = unboxedRow;
}
```

Which, again, could potentially be this:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>  ec;
public Double[][]                    ei;

// ...

for (int i = 0; i < ec.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<Double> row = ec.get(i);
    ei[i] = row.toArray(new Double[row.size()]);
}
```

Finally, please note that when you instantiate a new `Double[]`, the arrays initialize to `null` and *not* to `0`. If you try the following, you'll get a `NullPointerException`, though it will compile.

```
Double[] boxedArray = new Double[1];
double unboxed = boxedArray[0]; // equiv to "double unboxed = null;"
```

You need to be careful when unboxing, and make sure that you are handling nulls correctly.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks so much. When I change to ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> I can no longer ec.add(item) when item is a double[]?

Comment: It's tricky, because a `Double[]` is really an array of pointers that point to `Double`s (or null). A `double[]` is an array of doubles, so the actual _values_ are stored in the array, instead of just pointers. This is why a `double[]` never contains null. This makes it that we have to manually "box" our `doubles` into an array of pointers (`Double` references) in an array we specify. Java cannot just implicitly convert a `double[]` to a `Double[]`.

Comment: Another solution, if possible, is to simply use `double[]` instead of `Double[]`. So that a simple `clone()` can be done.

Answer (score 2):

```java
List<double[]> list = Arrays.asList(new double[]{1.1, 2.0}, new double[]{3.0, 5.8});
double[][] res = list.toArray(new double[list.size()][]);
// System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(res));
```

Same approach to convert ArrayList to 2d int array.

Answer (score 0):

Error is in the following lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ec.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<Double> row = ec.get(i);
    ei[i] = row.toArray(new double[row.size()]);
}
```

The first error will be resolved by replacing `ArrayList<Double>` with `Double[]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ec.size(); i++) {
    Double[] row = ec.get(i);
    ei[i] = row.toArray(new double[row.size()]);
}
```